# Teenage Revolution: How to overthrow parental dictatorship worldwide?

Tags: society, warfare, politics, children

Setting: Earth 2020.

Young people are sick of parental suppression, worldwide.

- They develop a vastly different understanding of social principles, compared to their parental generation.
- They can´t identify themselves with the prepotent oligarchs that mostly rule in politics and economics.
- They don´t see themselves politically represented in parliaments across the world.
- They are afraid of climate change.
- They believe, economic market growth has come to an end.
- They are fed up with consumerism. Except smartphones and internet.
- They don´t want to start a career after school and earn money later on.

The majority of kids share this conception, but stay passive and can´t wait to hold the newest Eyephone in hands. 
But as more and more information about social and ecologic grievances floods their digital means of communication (bubbles), the feeling that the end of the world, as we know it, might be near is overwhelming. Again, the vast majority stays ignorant or is agonized. But small subversive groups of young people begin to form, ready to take action. Groups split, divide themselves into those that try to make a change by peaceful manners and by talking seriously with their parents, and the others, that are less squeamishly and call to arms. These radical groups connect globally and plans start to form, how to take over.
They are willingly, but how shall they start?

Please help them overthrow the parental dictatorship worldwide and design a fresh tutorial showing them step by step, how to enter into action.

The kid´s advantages:

- Their number is legion. "42 percent of people are under the age of 25." [https://blogs.worldbank.org/opendata/chart-how-worlds-youth-population-changing]
- They live hidden in the middle of their societies, still inconspicuous.
- Some mislead grown ups support their aims, but are rarely found in tactically advantageous positions. Except some hopelessly gooders in Hollywood.
- They are all digitally linked.
- They are mentally flexible and innovative.
- They have nothing to loose, except their eyephones.

The parent´s advantages:

- The grownup´s number is also quite legion
- Grown ups have bigger economic resources
- They have bigger arms
- They make laws
- They have everything to loose
- and they pay for their kids telephone flatrate

  Note: Please identify for yourselves, what 'to take over' might mean. Parents promising, to take good care of nature from now on, is much too lax and boring. Eliminating everybody older than 18, is too heavy, and boring. Tutorials that promise a lot of fun for the young rebels, earn extra points.

Note: the 'young people' shouldn't be older than 18 years.

Please also note : that the follow up question might be s.th. like "How does a world look like, in which kids have taken over?"

Comment: "Kids" and "younger than 25"? Are you sure about your definition? I always thought kids were such before hitting puberty, which happens way earlier than 25.

Comment: "_mostly white oligarchs that rule_" um, white folks may have a considerable influence on the world stage, but they only make up something like 15% of the world's population. White oligarchs might not motivate the youth of India and China quite so much, for example, and those countries contain an awful lot of the world's population.

Comment: @StarfishPrime You're totally right. I change it a little.

Comment: "*Their number is legion. "42 percent of people are under the age of 25."*" but that doesn't mean those are *teenagers*. The 42 percent is QUITE a lot more than just those - people 20 and up are not teenagers *by definition*, same with children less than 13 years of age. And I sort of doubt a bunch of 8 year olds are going to be THAT effective in a revolution. Neither would be 4 year olds.

Comment: "*They live hidden in the middle of their societies, still inconspicuous.*" for what it's worth, teenagers are not as inconspicuous as they like to think. Adults *do* know of their existence and most of what they do. Adults just tend to turn a blind eye to them.

Comment: "*They are mentally flexible and innovative.*" I'd challenge that. Sure, *some* are but this is overly broad generalisation to make.

Comment: "*They have nothing to loose, except their eyephones.*" I'd challenge that, as well. In fact, it sort of clashes with the previous statement - mentally flexible and innovative *implies* capability of advanced reasoning and (not a dig at teenagers) yet this statement implies they aren't exactly as thoughtful. Sure, these are both stereotypes of teenagers but clash when applied at the same time.

Comment: All in all, this premise is widely unbelievable. It *has* been explored in fiction and usually children shows and young adult fiction but the pre-requirement is the adults are nearly useless. *Some* works try to address that somehow but overall it's hand-waved. The premise is simply not applicable were it to be true.

Comment: Apart from the scenario being utterly contrary to human nature, how is this query not story based?  The answer pretty much boils down to bullet points along a plot arc.

Comment: *"They don´t want to start a career after school and earn money later on":* so they plan to live like parasites on the backs of their parents?

Comment: In this scenario: The adults involved in Eyephone production and design stop work. Your youth unconditionally surrender. The end

Comment: You have to remember that the age distribution differs highly from country to country; many "developed" countries suffer aging (getting less offspring in comparison to the "old" people). E. g. https://www.statista.com/statistics/265759/world-population-by-age-and-region/ in Africa over 40% of the population are under 15 years old, in Europe that age group only makes 16%.

Comment: Africa for example suffers greatly from climate change (motivation), corruption and dictatorship (motivation). There are many people in your wanted age group but they are less educated and connected than for example in Europe (statistically, don't take that racist). The other question is, would a worldwide revolution work at all (at least as a starting point for your story) or would it make more sense to see the world wide revolution as the aim of that movement which has not been reached at the begin of your story - the children/teenagers were able to overthrow and hold some countries

Comment: but at some point the frontiers got stuck and you have a dualism (like in the cold war) with the elderly dominated and teenage dominated block. How would life look there? Would the kids and the adults be oppressed in each opposite country in fear of a counterrevolution? Are there adults/kids in the other block who secretly send messages to inform about the "enemy"?

Comment: And would some rights be bound to age in the teenage dominated countries, for example you loose the right to vote if you turn over 25 (like oppression of academics in German GDR)

Comment: As I doubt that a worldwide teenage revolution would be probable, the question would be how those teenage ruled countries could protect themselves from a counter revolution - they either are not interesting enough or not a threat enough to be reconquered, or they are in possession of either dangerous weapons or have a monopoly for resources that the adult block needs (the latter could also CAUSE a war). Or the blocks can't risk a war to lose backing of their own supporters as long as the other side hasn't done anything really bad to justify a first strike

Comment: @Cee Mon: thanks a lot for your considerations. Yes worldwide is quite a big word, but it doesn't necessarily imply, that every teenager in every country is involved into the movement. But several  groups might connect worldwide, for e.g. groups in the northern hemisphere might solidarize themselves with groups, that are directly threatened by global warming.

Comment: Most of the teenagers I know would forget that the revolution was today entirely. Those that bothered to learn and use their phone's calendar would still show up late, in the wrong clothes for street fighting (or the weather), hungry, and needing to use the bathroom. They would complain about how the revolution was so poorly organized.

Comment: You might be interested in *The Grandfather's War* by Murray Leinster - one of the [Med Ship](https://www.baen.com/med-ship.html) Stories - that has a similar premise... that the youth of a world end up in a situation where they are at war with the older generation due to suspiciously specific circumstances, and the story mentions some potential strengths and potential weaknesses of such a cultural division.